# Searching in a li with multiple search criteria

Tags: jquery, search, criteria

Multiple search criteria in a list

I have a list like below

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <dl class="p_list1">
            <dd id="name">
                <b>Car</b></dd>
            <dd id="company">
                Honda, Hyundai, Toyota, Suzuki</dd>
        </dl>
    </li>
    <li>
        <dl class="p_list2">
            <dd id="name">
                <b>Bike</b></dd>
            <dd id="company">
                Honda, Yamaha, Suzuki</dd>
        </dl>
    </li>
    <li>
        <dl class="p_list3">
            <dd id="name">
                <b>Truck</b></dd>
            <dd id="company">
                Tata, Volvo, Mahindra</dd>
        </dl>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I am using two text boxes txtName and txtCompany to search in this list.
Based on one textbox value or both the textbox values i need to show and hide the list.

1. If user search in txtName like "c" it has to show item 1st and 3rd. (txtCompany is empty)
2. If user search in txtcompany like "Hon" it has to show first and second list. (txtname is empty)
3. If txtName like "c" and user search on txtCompany then it has to search from list with item 1st and 3rd

I have used below jquery

```
(
        function ($) {
            jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function (a, i, m) {
                return (a.textContent || a.innerText || "").toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
            };
            function listFilter(list) {

                $('#txtName').change(function () {
                    var filter = $(this).val(); if (filter) { $(list).find("dd[id='name']:not(:Contains(" + filter + "))").parent().parent().slideUp(); $(list).find("dd[id='name']:Contains(" + filter + ")").parent().parent().slideDown(); }
                    else
                    { $(list).find("li").slideDown(); }
                    return false;
                }
               ).keyup(function () { $(this).change(); });


                $('#txtCompany').change(function () {
                    var filter = $(this).val(); if (filter) { $(list).find("dd[id='company']:not(:Contains(" + filter + "))").parent().parent().slideUp(); $(list).find("dd[id='company']:Contains(" + filter + ")").parent().parent().slideDown(); }
                    else
                    { $(list).find("li").slideDown(); }
                    return false;
                }
               ).keyup(function () { $(this).change(); });


            }



            $(function () {
                listFilter($("#list"));
            }
            );
        } (jQuery));
```

now the problem is when I start searching with one text box its working fine, when I use both the search criteria then it will start searching based in current text box keypress.
I know this is because I have written the change event for text box and its not considering other text box values :(

Here's [a link to the test I have created](http://jsfiddle.net/pankajmotiyar/J7hEY/3/)

Comment: thanks for the help:)
I need "and" search, ie if the name starts with "c" and company like "h" then it has to show first list.
I am working on the code to solve this :)

Comment: Then it is straightforward: taking my answer as a starting point, you should invert what you do with the conditions for slideUp and slideDown. In particular, write two instructions for the two conditions on slideUp, so that if wither one is matched the element is hidden, and only one for the slideDown, so that it is shown only if both are met. 

**see code in my answer**

Answer (score 1):

This code should do the trick:

**EDIT:** This code filters the elements according to a OR combination of the two conditions.

```
 (
        function ($) {
            jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function (a, i, m) {
                return (a.textContent || a.innerText || "").toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
            };
            var nameFilter, companyFilter;    //store their values

            function onConditionChange (nameFilter, companyFilter) {

                     var hideCondition =  "dd" + (companyFilter ? "[id='company']:not(:Contains(" + companyFilter + "))" : "") + (nameFilter ? "[id='name']:not(:Contains(" + nameFilter + "))" : "");

                    if (nameFilter || companyFilter) { 

                        $(list).find(hideCondition).parent().parent().slideUp();
                        if (nameFilter) {
                                                    $(list).find("dd[id='name']:Contains(" + nameFilter + ")").parent().parent().slideDown();
                                                }
                                                if (companyFilter) {
                                                        $(list).find("dd[id='company']:Contains(" + companyFilter + ")").parent().parent().slideDown();                         
                                                }                        
                    } else { 
                        $(list).find("li").slideDown(); 
                    }
                    return false;
                }            

            function listFilter(list) {

                $('#txtName').change(function() {
                    nameFilter = $(this).val();
                    onConditionChange(nameFilter, companyFilter);
                }
               ).keyup(function () { $(this).change(); });


                $('#txtCompany').change(function() {
                    companyFilter = $(this).val();
                    onConditionChange(nameFilter, companyFilter);
                }
               ).keyup(function () { $(this).change(); });


            }



            $(function () {
                listFilter($("#list"));
            }
            );
        } (jQuery));
```

I forked your fiddle so you can see it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eLnug/)

Basically you keep track of both conditions, and use them for the filters, if they are not null (or at least one is not null).

I  tried to enforce a DRYer version, with less duplicated code. However, it can be still improved, but it should solve your problem.

**EDIT**

After reading comment, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TeSZn/) it is a version that filters the elements putting the two search conditions in AND.

```
 (
    function ($) {
        jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function (a, i, m) {
            return (a.textContent || a.innerText || "").toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
        };
        var nameFilter, companyFilter;    //store their values

        function onConditionChange (nameFilter, companyFilter) {

                 var showCondition =  "dd" + (companyFilter ? "[id='company']:Contains(" + companyFilter + ")" : "") + (nameFilter ? "[id='name']:Contains(" + nameFilter + ")" : "");

                if (nameFilter || companyFilter) { 
                    if (nameFilter) {                        
                        $(list).find("dd[id='name']:not(:Contains(" + nameFilter + "))").parent().parent().slideUp();
                    }
                    if (companyFilter) {
                        $(list).find("dd[id='company']:not(:Contains(" + companyFilter + "))").parent().parent().slideUp();                            
                    }

                    $(list).find(showCondition).parent().parent().slideDown();

                } else { 
                    $(list).find("li").slideDown(); 
                }
                return false;
            }            

        function listFilter(list) {

            $('#txtName').change(function() {
                nameFilter = $(this).val();
                onConditionChange(nameFilter, companyFilter);
            }
           ).keyup(function () { $(this).change(); });


            $('#txtCompany').change(function() {
                companyFilter = $(this).val();
                onConditionChange(nameFilter, companyFilter);
            }
           ).keyup(function () { $(this).change(); });


        }



        $(function () {
            listFilter($("#list"));
        }
        );
    } (jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are encountering problem because you are using same ID for multiple DOM elements which is not allowed. Try assigning classes instead of IDs if you want to call same jquery function to multiple DOM elements.

I am marking issues in your markup:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <dl class="p_list1">
            <dd id="name"> <!--OK to have an ID here---->
                <b>Car</b></dd>
            <dd id="company"><!--OK to have an ID here---->
                Honda, Hyundai, Toyota, Suzuki</dd>
        </dl>
    </li>
    <li>
        <dl class="p_list2">
            <dd id="name"><!--ID repeated, jquery function won't run for this event---->
                <b>Bike</b></dd>
            <dd id="company"><!--ID repeated, jquery function won't run for this event---->
                Honda, Yamaha, Suzuki</dd>
        </dl>
    </li>
    <li>
        <dl class="p_list3">
            <dd id="name"><!--ID repeated, jquery function won't run for this event---->
                <b>Truck</b></dd>
            <dd id="company"><!--ID repeated, jquery function won't run for this event---->
                Tata, Volvo, Mahindra</dd>
        </dl>
    </li>
</ul>
```